# In alexa video skill how to stop addVideoAppLaunchDirective ? iam playing video using addVideoAppLaunchDirective

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have an Alexa skill which plays using addVideoAppLaunchDirective(). my problem is when I stop the skill using stop intent Alexa only responds with the text which I gave, after that the video continues playing. with stop intent, I want to completely stop the streaming of video.

The code which I execute during stop intent is as follows

```
handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = 'Goodbye!';
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder

            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.withShouldEndSession(true)
            //.stop()
            .getResponse();
    }
```